# Two Consumer group and Two Topics under single spring boot kafka

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm new to spring boot kafka and trying to connect my spring-boot kafka application (ms-consumer-app) with two different topics associated with two different consumer group id, both need to be under the ms-consumer-app (Spring boot kafka).

**Code Summary**

1. I have two consumerFactory bean method - consumerFactoryG1 with myGroupId-1 and consumerFactoryG2 with myGroupId-2
2. Two method annotated with  @KafkaListener for its corresponding topics ,groupId and containerFactory
3. Association:
   container Factory= "consumerFactoryG1", topic = "test-G1", groupId = "myGroupId-1" and container Factory= "consumerFactoryG2", topic = "test-G2", groupId = "myGroupId-2"

However, when i start the ms-consumer-app (Spring boot kafka), i get "org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException"

```
ERROR [ms-consumer-app] --- [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata.checkUnauthorizedTopics - [Consumer clientId=consumer-myGroupId-1-3, groupId=myGroupId-1] Topic authorization failed for topics [test-G1]
ERROR [ms-consumer-app] --- [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.error - Authorization Exception and no authorizationExceptionRetryInterval set
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [test-G1]
```

My KafkaConsumerConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactoryG1() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "myGroupId-1");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer());
    }
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactoryG1() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactoryG1());
        concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.setMissingTopicsFatal(false);
        return concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactoryG2() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "myGroupId-2");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer());
    }
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactoryG2() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactoryG2());
        concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.setMissingTopicsFatal(false);
        return concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
    }
    
     @KafkaListener(topics = "test-G1", groupId = "myGroupId-1", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactoryG1")
        public void getTopicsG1(@RequestBody String emp) {
        System.out.println("Kafka event consumed is: " + emp);
    }
         @KafkaListener(topics = "test-G2", groupId = "myGroupId-2", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactoryG2")
        public void getTopicsG2(@RequestBody String emp) {
        System.out.println("Kafka event consumed is: " + emp);
    }
}
```

Any leads would be of more help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since your configurations are almost the same, you don't need two factories; you can use Spring Boot's auto-configured factory (via application.properties or .yml). You have already specified the `groupId` on the `@KafkaListener`s and this overrides the factory `group.id`.

That is not relevant to your error though; your broker must have security configured and you are not allowed to consume from those topics.

See the Kafka documentation for information about authorization: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_authz